# shared printer print command in VBScript

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vbscript

I am trying to create a Batch file(using VB Script) in order to print a doc file, but the problem I am facing is that, the printer is shared printer in our office and when I run my following code , It says "Windows cannot print due to a problem with the current printer setup". Here is my code

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Iqbaltaj\Downloads\Test.docx")

objDoc.PrintOut()
objWord.Visible        = False
objWord.ScreenUpdating = False
objWord.ActiveDocument.PrintOut False
objWord.ActiveDocument.Close 0 
objWord.Quit
Set objWord = Nothing
```

and the location of my shared printer is "\\cap003\HP LaserJet P3005 PCL6".
Kindly tell me what line of code should I add , in order to print the document.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `objWord.PrintOut()` instead of `objDoc.PrintOut()`.
You can also add printer setup, try this:

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Iqbaltaj\Downloads\Test.docx")

objWord.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup(Printer:="HP LaserJet P3005 PCL6", DoNotSetAsSysDefault:=1)
objWord.PrintOut()
...
objWord.Documents.Close()
objWord.Quit()
```

This is assuming "HP LaserJet P3005 PCL6" is the name of this printer (of course).
You can check the printers installed via [PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx#Y500).

Comment: I have tried that code it says Expected ")" at line 4 Char:41. I have also tried this line of Code:
`objWord.Application.ActivePrinter = "\\cap003\HP LaserJet P3005 PCL6"`
 But it says "Windows cannot print due to a problem with the current printer setup". I have checked in Event viewer as well, but there is not much helpful info. Kindly help Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's just a syntax issue? If this code s'd run as VBS, and as there no Optional arguments in VBS, the syntax like: `named_arg:=value` will not work. Try `objWord.Application.ActivePrinter "HP LaserJet P3005 PCL6", 1`

Comment: Sorry, my bad (copy/paste typo), ActivePrinter is a property, not a method. I was mean to try `objWord.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup`, posted above in my answer, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

If this [example code](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrintUsingWordVbs) I found is correct then looks like the syntax is...

```
objWord.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup "HP LaserJet P3005 PCL6", , , 1
```

Well, in case that not help at all, here is something more that can try...

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set oPrinters = WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections

strPrinterName = "HP LaserJet P3005 PCL6"
strPrinterPath = "\\cap003\" & strPrinterName
bIsMapped = False

For i = 0 to oPrinters.Count - 1 Step 2
    If strPrinterName = oPrinters.Item(i+1) Then
        bIsMapped = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo "Mapped: " & bIsMapped

If Not bIsMapped Then
    WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection strPrinterPath
End If
```

Comment: This link is good for the posted question.http://www.strathweb.com/2012/10/remote-printing-with-asp-net-web-api-in-windows-service/

Comment: Also I want to share with you guys ...This link

http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/msoffice/word/

It is really helpful